# Funcão $.getJSON retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo problemas em um sistema que baixa a foto de 10 artistas de um TOP 10.
Segue a função:

```
function baixarCapa(capa) {
   $.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", {
       q: '"' + capa + '"',
       v: '1.0'
   }, function(data) {
       return data.responseData.results[0].url;
   });
}
```

E mais abaixo:

```
showTopMusicas: function(){
    this.ajax('callCustomApi', ['getTop'], function(dados) {
        if (!dados || !dados.length) {
            return;
        }

        var html = '';
        capa = '';

        for (var i=0; i< dados.length; i++) {
            var nome = CentovaApi.formataNomeMusica(dados[i]);
            if (!nome) {
                continue;
            }

            capa = nome.split('/').pop();

            console.log(baixarCapa(capa));

            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + baixarCapa(capa) + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + (i+1) + 'º</td>';
            html += '<td>' + nome.split('/').pop() + '</td>';
            //html += '<td>' + dados[i].count + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }
        $('#table_top_musicas').find('tbody').html( html );
    }, true);
},
```

Tudo funciona, com esse exceção das capas, aparece apenas `undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua função `baixarCapa` retorna `undefined` porque você não especifica nenhum retorno nela. Você especifica retorno num *callback* passado para ela, mas ele só é executado mais tarde (é **assíncrono**), e não é possível capturar o seu retorno.

Como você só recebe os dados naquele *callback*, precisa usá-los ali mesmo, seja diretamente, ou chamando outra função e passando esses dados adiante. E portanto não dá para montar o HTML da maneira como você está fazendo, que espera que a capa já esteja disponível.  O que você pode fazer é reservar um lugar para a capa no HTML, mas só colocar a imagem mais tarde.

Por exemplo, você pode fazer assim:

```
baixarCapa(capa, i);
html += '<td data-capa="' + i + '"></td>';
```

Com uma função assim:

```
function baixarCapa(capa, item) {
   $.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", {
       q: '"' + capa + '"',
       v: '1.0'
   }, function(data) {
       var url = data.responseData.results[0].url;
       $('[data-capa=' + item + ']').html('<img src="' + url + '">');
   });
}
```

Comment: Funcionou NA HORA! Você é campeão amigo. Muito obrigado.